# How to align WPF Toolkit Color Picker position just below Toolbar control

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit

**Question**: How can we align famous [WPF Toolkit Color Picker](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/ColorPicker) position just below to WPF's [Toolbar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/toolbar-overview) control?

Or, could we include Color picker in the toolbar itself? The idea is to let the Color Picker appear when user clicks on the "Color" button shown in the toolbar below, but that I can accomplish using C# code.

So far, I've gotten this close by using the XAML shown below:

[image]

**XAML**:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp_ExceedToolkit_test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp_ExceedToolkit_test"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <DockPanel Margin="0,0,660,0">
        <ToolBarTray DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <ToolBar Height="26">
                <Button Command="New" Content="New" />
                <Button Command="Open" Content="Open" />
                <Button Command="Save" Content="Color" />
            </ToolBar>
        </ToolBarTray>
        <xctk:ColorPicker Name="ColorPicker1" AdvancedButtonHeader="TestColor" Height="15" DisplayColorAndName="True" Margin="0,5,0,358" />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: `The idea is to let the Color Picker appear when user clicks on the "Color" button shown` visibility is this ur looking for?

Comment: I mean as u already placed under the `ToolBarTray` i assume the position is right on click on clr button u wanna display `xctk:ColorPicker`  the use the visibility prop to hide and display the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or, could we include Color picker in the toolbar itself?

Sure:

```
<ToolBarTray>
    <ToolBar>
        <Button Command="New" Content="New" />
        <Button Command="Open" Content="Open" />
        <xctk:ColorPicker Name="ColorPicker1" 
                          AdvancedButtonHeader="TestColor"
                          DisplayColorAndName="True"/>
    </ToolBar>
</ToolBarTray>
```

You may also use a `ToggleButton` that opens a `Popup`:

```
<ToolBarTray>
    <ToolBar>
        <Button Command="New" Content="New" />
        <Button Command="Open" Content="Open" />
        <ToggleButton x:Name="tb" Content="Save" />
        <Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=tb}"
                       PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=tb}"
                       Placement="Bottom"
                       StaysOpen="False">
            <xctk:ColorPicker Name="ColorPicker1" 
                              AdvancedButtonHeader="TestColor"
                              DisplayColorAndName="True" />
        </Popup>
    </ToolBar>
</ToolBarTray>
```

Comment: I like the second `XAML` of your response but it's having a display issue. But since it demands an other post, I've posted another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55764295/1232087). However, your first `XAML` has actually answered my question in the post so I'm marking it as an answer.