# Display issue with WPF toolkit Color Picker inside toolbar

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpftoolkit

Following XAML in WPF is displaying the dropdown button of the WPF Toolkit's [Color Picker](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/ColorPicker) outside the [toolbar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/toolbar-overview) as shown in the screenshot below.

**Question**: How can I make the dropdown button display inside the toolbar (something similar to what we have in MS WORD toolbar's color picker)? Obviously, I'm missing something in the XAML below.

**Screenshot of the Toolbar with Color Picker**:

[image]

```
<DockPanel Margin="0,0,660,0">
<ToolBarTray>
    <ToolBar>
        <Button Command="New" Content="New" />
        <Button Command="Open" Content="Open" />
        <ToggleButton x:Name="tb" Content="Color" />
        <Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=tb}"
                       PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=tb}"
                       Placement="Bottom"
                       StaysOpen="False">
            <xctk:ColorPicker Name="ColorPicker1" 
                              AdvancedButtonHeader="Advanced"
                              DisplayColorAndName="True" />
        </Popup>
    </ToolBar>
</ToolBarTray>
</DockPanel>
```

**EDIT**: Added  DockPanel tag in the XAML - in case that is making any difference

Comment: Maybe your toolbar can't fit because you set the right margin to 660. What happens if you remove the margin on that dockpanel?

Comment: @Andy Per your suggestion, I removed the margin, but it still the same issue.

Comment: @nam: I am not sure that you mean by "inside". The `ColorPicker` is displayed in a popup. Where do you want to display it exactly?

Comment: @mm8 Not the popup itself but, as mentioned in my post above, the popup button is what I would like displayed inside the toolbar. Currently, as shown in my screenshot above, the popup button is displaying outside the toolbar. Liked in `MS WORD` the dropdown button of the color picker is inside their toolbar (Ribbon) but when the dropdown button is clicked the color picker popups outside the Toolbar/Ribbon.

Comment: @nam: You mean the "Color" button? Or the ComboBox?

Comment: @mm8 The selected color along with the dropdown button of the color picker that is to the right of the selected color.

Comment: @nam: Replace the `ToggleButton` with a `ColorPicker` and remove the `Popup`?

Comment: @mm8 Yes, something similar to what you suggested in your first `XAML` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55737818/how-to-align-wpf-toolkit-color-picker-position-just-below-toolbar-control) except that in that case it displays only the dropdown on toolbar but not the selected color to the left of the dropdown. So, probably some changes there will do the trick.

Comment: @nam: It should display the selected colour if there is one.